# How to restart the build method on TabPage in flutter app with auto_route package

Tags: flutter, routes, auto

Hi a use auto_route package in flutter app. How to restart the build method on TabPage or not save the stack state when switching tabs. I should have an animation run in the build method on TabPage every time I switch a tab in the navigation bar. But the build method is not called when I click the buttons in the navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

in your @MaterialAutoRouter() add this property to the tab bar child that you want to rebuild every time the user taps on the item:

```
AutoRoute(path: 'your_path', page: YourPage, maintainState: false), //<- with this the tab will rebuild every time.
```

if you want more control over the action, and you have a nested route, in alternative you could add a listener

```
class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> with AutoRouteAware{ // <- add this
AutoRouteObserver? _observer;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    _observer = RouterScope.of(context).firstObserverOfType<AutoRouteObserver>();
    if (_observer != null) {
      _observer?.subscribe(this, context.router.currentChild!);
    }

    context.tabsRouter.addListener(() {
      if (context.tabsRouter.activeIndex == 1) { //your tab index here
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT
      }
    });
  }
```

if the tab router is not nested into an emptyRouterPage, simply extend with AutoRouteAwareStateMixin.

```
class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> with AutoRouteAwareStateMixin<YourWidget> { // <- add this

void didInitTabRoute(TabPageRoute? previousRoute) async {
//do something on first tap
}

void didChangeTabRoute(TabPageRoute previousRoute) async {
//do something on successives taps
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are the same user that commented on my article. I'll give the same answer here. this is not related to the autoroute package itself but it is the default behavior of a bottombar navigation. The objective being to always minimize the number of rebuilds necessary for your UI.

I didn't test it but you could try to make your tab a stateful widget (if it isn't already) and modify this behavior with the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<YourWidget>`:

```dart
class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<YourWidget>{

 // Here you build your Widget after calling the super method
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
 super.build(context) 
 return Container(); 
} 

// the important part is returning false here
@override bool get wantKeepAlive => false; 

 }
```

Comment: ```dart
class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<YourWidget>{

 // Here you build your Widget after calling the super method
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
 super.build(context) 
 return Container(); 
} 

// the important part is returning false here
@override bool get wantKeepAlive => false; 

 }
```